# Is it possible to write if-statement for errors in r?

Tags: r, error-handling

for example, I want to fill in empty lists by lots of data frames(using web-scraping).
The most part of web data behaves nicely, but minor part not(for example, the absence of data in imdb rating's page).

Is it possible to create an if-statement, such that:

```
if(Error "bla-bla-bla" exists){
    then create data.frame(that consists of NA's)
    and add data.frame to list
```

It will be nice to see a pattern or smth like that.
Many thanks!

Comment: `try` is a good place to start with error handling

Comment: also `tryCatch` or `plyr::failwith`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `try` and examine the class of the object:

```
x = "5"
y = try(x+x, silent=TRUE)
if(class(y) == "try-catch") {
  ## Do something
}
```

If you examine `y`,

```
R> y
[1] "Error in x + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in x + x: non-numeric argument to binary operator>
```

You can extract the error message, `attr(y, "condition")`. Also look at `tryCatch`.